# ubuntu Iptables VPN connection only

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, vpn, iptables

I want to setup an internet connection that only goes through a PPTP VPN and if that VPN connection fails, I want to nothing to be able to access the net and nobody to be able to access me. What I want is all traffic going through VPN only, so in short I want to make the equivalent of a VPN Killswitch happen with iptables

I have tried
iptables -A INPUT -d 0.1.2.3 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
where 0.1.2.3 is the vpn address

but that doesn't seem to work
I have also tried
iptables -A INPUT !-d 0.1.2.3 -j DROP
but that also doesn't seem to do the job

ifconfig says eth0 is my ethernet hardware address
and ppp0 is point to point protocol
do I need to add filters of the protocol to make sure no traffic connects outside of VPN address?

Answer (score 0):

Are TUN/TAP are enabled? Check it by type

> cat /dev/net/tun

if the result "File descriptor in bad state", it means TUN/TAP already enabled, else it disabled.

Try

> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE